# AWS DocumentDB vector indexing options missing apparently

Tags: vector, indexing, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to create a [vector index in DocumentDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/vector-search.html) but I keep getting an error following the documentation's example:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
  { "<vectorField>": "vector" },
  { "name": "<indexName>",
    "vectorOptions": {
      "dimensions": <number_of_dimensions>,
      "similarity": " <euclidean> | <cosine> | <dotProduct> ",
      "lists": <number_of_lists> 
    }
  }
);
```

When I try to create my index on the "embedding" field in my collection, I use the following:

```
db.collection.createIndex({
    embedding: 'vector',
}, {
    name: "vectorEmbeddingIdx",
    vectorOptions: {
        dimensions: 2000,
        similarity: "euclidean",
        lists: 1,
    }
})
```

Which results in the following error:

```
MongoServerError: vectorOptions input is required to create vector indexes
```

I've been using the almighty Google but finding little documentation on my situation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you also try using double quotes around the fields like `"vectorOptions"`? Does that make any difference?

Comment: @ArpitJain Unfortunately no, in JS { "test": 1 } is the same as { test: 1 }. I tried it anyway just for the hell of it but no luck.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I also tried through pymongo running "db.runCommand({})", and the error message states that "vector" is an invalid type of index. I also tried running the latest maintenance upgrade, as well as making sure the engine versions matches the ones in mentioned in the documentation and release notes. I have reached out to DocumentDB team at AWS. 

Extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the index creation only works if there are not other properties on the document that will hold the vector. The index creation should also be run using `runCommand` or `db.command` from `pymongo`:

```
db.command({"createIndexes": <COLLECTION>, 
    "indexes": [{ 
      "key": {<VECTOR_FIELD>:"vector"}, 
      "vectorOptions": 
         {"dimensions": <N_DIMS>, 
         "similarity": "cosine",
         "lists": <N_DOCUMENTS/1000>,
         }, 
      "name": <index_name>
      }] 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DocumentDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/vector-search.html#w5aac21c11c11) says,

> In certain drivers, such as mongosh and Java, using the `vectorOptions` parameters in `createIndex` may result in an error. In such cases, we recommend using `runCommand`.

I'd recommend using `runCommand` or equivalent for the driver you're using, as suggested by `Charmander_` above.